# Firefox driver returning null

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, junit

So I am using Selenium with JUnit. The issue I'm having is that when I configure my firefox driver using the following method, the driver returns *null*.

This is the function that configures it-

```
public WebDriver ConfigureFirefox(WebDriver Driver){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/Users/wshaikh/Downloads/geckodriver");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    Driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    return Driver;
}
```

Here is how it is being used in the Test Setup-

```
@Before
public void SetupTest()
{
    Driver = testHelper.ConfigureFirefox(Driver);
    checkPointPage = new CheckPointPage(Driver);

    Driver.get(URL);
}
```

I keep getting a NullPointer exception. After stepping through the code, I figured out the Driver keeps returning null and do not know why.

I am using a Mac.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `driver` with the `capabilities`. You also don't need to send the `driver` to `ConfigureFirefox`

```
public WebDriver ConfigureFirefox() {  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/Users/wshaikh/Downloads/geckodriver");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

    return driver;
}

@Before
public void SetupTest() {
    Driver = testHelper.ConfigureFirefox();
    checkPointPage = new CheckPointPage(Driver);

    Driver.get(URL);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but now i'm getting this - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property"

Comment: Nevermind. i changed the "webdriver.fire.marionnete" to "webdriver.gecko.driver". That fixed it. Thanks!